# Why should you put the image size in HTML code

Tags: html, image-size

Let's say you create an image. You do:

```
<img src="_images/stackoverflow.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Stack Overflow">
```

Let's say that image defaults to a width of 300 and a height of 300. Is there any reason to specify it, or should you just leave that field blank?

Side question: is the alt command mandatory?

Comment: Side answer: no it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring width and height properties on your HTML tag, you are controlling the size of the image to be displayed, specially if the image size is too large and would fit in the entire webpage. What you are doing is an Inline style.

The alt is an optional  property(the image tag works without setting an alt property). However, web crawlers use alt tag to index images on your website. So, your alt property should have values relevant to the content of your image so that search engines can easily find your website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specific the size of your image.

You should put this to prevent showing so many visual changes on your page while the images are loading.

Bringing something from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp)

> **Tip**: Always specify both the height and width attributes for images. If height and width are set, the space required for the image is reserved when the page is loaded. However, without these attributes, the browser does not know the size of the image, and cannot reserve the appropriate space to it. The effect will be that the page layout will change during loading (while the images load).
>
> **Tip**: Downsizing a large image with the height and width attributes
>   forces a user to download the large image (even if it looks small on
>   the page). To avoid this, rescale the image with a program before
>   using it on a page.

But it's not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp) :

> Always specify both the `height` and `width` attributes for images. If
>   `height` and `width` are set, the space required for the image is
>   reserved when the page is loaded. However, without these attributes,
>   the browser or user agent does not know the size of the image, hence
>   it cannot reserve the appropriate space to it. The effect will be that
>   the page layout will change during loading (while the images load).

---

> is the alt command mandatory?

**NO**, it is not mandatory. However, it is really good to always include it as you probably already know why, if not the purpose of alt attributes is to provide a description of the contents of an image file.

One of the most cited uses of alt attributes is to provide text for visitors who can’t see images in their browsers. This includes visitors using browsers that cannot display images or have image display disabled, visually impaired visitors, and those visitors who use screen readers. If a viewer can see your images, alt attributes will also show when the user hovers over your image.

Also, there is a really good post [HERE](https://yoast.com/image-seo-alt-tag-and-title-tag-optimization/) about image SEO, which is related to `alt` tag.